# Find the line that passes by $P=(1,-2,3)$ and has angle $45$ and $60$ respectively with the $x$ and $y$ axis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have

$$P=(1,-2,3)$$
And the x-axis with direction vector $(1,0,0)$ and y-axis with direction vector $(0,1,0)$.

By the angle formula:

$$\cos\theta = \frac{|\vec u\cdot\vec v|}{||\vec u||||\vec v||}$$

So I need to force the angle between the $x$ axis to be $45$ and the angle between the $y$ axis to be $60$. The problem is that when I consider the direction vector of my lineto be $(a,b,c)$ and I plug in the formula I don't know what to do next:

$$\cos 45= \frac{|(1,0,0)\cdot(a,b,c)|}{1||\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}||}$$
and
$$\cos 60= \frac{|(0,1,0)\cdot(a,b,c)|}{1||\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}||}$$

I can't solve for $a,b,c$ and I don't know how to use the point in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
You're on right track so far!
Next, let the angle with z-axis be $\alpha $, you get :
$$\cos \alpha = \frac{|(0,0,1)\cdot(a,b,c)|}{1||\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}||}$$

---

Squaring and adding these 3 equations you get :
$$\cos^245 + \cos^260 + \cos^2\alpha = 1$$

Solve $\cos\alpha $ and you will have direction vector of the line